# Trouble with ellipsoid collision

Tags: collision-detection, linear-algebra

I am currently trying to develop a routine in C which should determine whether two axis aligned ellipsoids collide. My current approach is to use a 4-dimensional matrix representation for each ellipsoid (let's call the matrices A and B) and then calculate the characteristic polynomial using f(n) = det(A + n*B). I also assume that the ellipsoid B has its center at (0, 0, 0), to simplify things a bit. Then, the resulting determinant becomes [this expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYjY6.gif).

There (a, b, c) are the semi-axes of A and (d, e, f) the semi-axes of B. (x, y, z) is the distance vector between them.

I calculated the characteristic polynomial then using Wolfram Alpha (I did it per hand also, but the expressions began to fill nearly a whole page) and obtained this result for the characteristic equation [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Klh7.gif).

I now used the following C code for the expressions:

```
double abc2 = a2 * b2 * c2;
double def2 = d2 * e2 * f2;
double bcd2 = b2 * c2 * d2;
double ace2 = a2 * c2 * e2;
double abf2 = a2 * b2 * f2;
double cde2 = c2 * d2 * e2;
double bdf2 = b2 * d2 * f2;
double aef2 = a2 * e2 * f2;

double c_4 = abc2;
double c_3 = x2*b2*c2 + bcd2 + y2*a2*c2 + ace2 + z2*a2*b2 + abf2 - abc2;
double c_2 = x2*c2*e2 + y2*c2*d2 + cde2 + x2*b2*f2 + z2*b2*d2 + bdf2 - bcd2 + y2*a2*f2 + z2*a2*e2 + aef2 - ace2 - abf2;
double c_1 = y2*e2*f2 + y2*d2*f2 + z2*d2*e2 + def2 - cde2 - bdf2 - aef2;
double c_0 = -def2;
```

where a2, b2, etc. are defined as the squares of the corresponding values. I also multiplied the characteristic polynomial with the product of all squared semi-axes to avoid divisions in my calculations (which doesn't change the results of my collision detection algorithm). I then use a variation of the Sturm chain to count the number of positive and negative roots. If two positive roots exist, the ellipsoids should collide.

But somehow I obtain invalid results, for example if a = b = c = d = e = f = 1 and (x, y, z) = (10, 0, 0), I obtain one positive root and 3 negative roots. However, x = 1.9 yields the exact same number of roots (the spheres should definitely collide there), while x = 1.0 for example gives one positive and one negative root (I've checked the results again with Wolfram Alpha, which does confirm those).

I don't know where my mistake is, since I implemented that algorithm with the exact same ansatz in 2D for ellipses and it is working perfectly there. But in 3D the results are completely wrong and I can't find the reason why. I previously did the calculations for B being a unit sphere only (completely separated from the calculations above), but the problem occured there, too.

I hope, somebody can point out my mistake or error in thought here, since I am totally out of ideas.

Regards, Hadeweka